# How to get sum of specific column at specific row range in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is my table :

```
Id       Name      Price      Session
----------------------------------------
1        abcd      1000       07.00 AM
1        abcd      1000       07.00 AM
5        mnop      NULL       12.00 AM
5        mnop      NULL       12.00 AM
5        mnop      1000       12.00 AM
```

This result that I hope :

```
Id       Name      Price      Session
--------------------------------------
1        abcd      2000       07.00 AM
5        mnop      1000       12.00 AM
```

How can I sum column `Price` at specific row range?

Comment: Hint: GROUP BY, SUM.

Comment: Side note: I will never understand why people call **non-unique** columns `Id`. That really makes no sense whatsoever.

Comment: You should have a look at [`GROUP BY`](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp) with aggregate functions.

You need to group by all columns that you need in your result and aggregate (`sum`) the one column you wish to sum up.

Comment: You may have oversimplified your sample data. Would it be possible to have another record with Id=1, Name='xyz', Price=3000, Session='08.00 PM'? How would that record alter your results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Other approach without `group by` clause is `SUM()`.. `over`

```
SELECT DISTINCT
   Id, Name,
   SUM(Price) OVER(PARTITION BY ID, Name, Session) [Price],
   [Session]
FROM <table>;
```

Result :

```
Id       Name      Price      Session
--------------------------------------
1        abcd      2000       07.00 AM
5        mnop      1000       12.00 AM
```

Comment: Well, it's always possible to obfuscate a query, but why would you do this. Why construct an aggregation per row only to dismiss it later? Makes no sense to me.

Answer (score 1):

Include a `group by` clause in your query.  All srlected columns not using an aggregate function are slso listed in the group by clause.

```
Select id ,name ,session ,sum (price)
From table
Group by id, name, session
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this with a SUM on Price and finish with a GROUP BY.

the Microsoft doc for GROUP BY :
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-group-by-transact-sql

And a short example :

```
SELECT Id, Name, Session, SUM(Price) AS Price
FROM Table
GROUP BY Id, Name, Session
```